# Cross join of different data elements to create a Bipartite graph in R

Tags: r, igraph

I want to create a bipartite graph (in r) of Conditions and Treaters based on actual events. I can do this easily if I can get my data converted to the right format as in the table below:

|  | Physio | GP | Chemist | Psych | Dentist |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **BackPain** | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| **Depression** | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| **Flu** | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| **Anxiety** | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| **Toothache** | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

For further clarification, the leftmost column rows are "Conditions" and the columns are "Treaters" (obviously ficticious), with the intersection = 1, if the Treater was vistied for the specific Condition.

My data is in long format below. It consists of a patient id, the term that contains the Condition/Treater word and a type which denotes if the term is a Condition or Treater type.

```
df <-
  data.frame(
    id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5),
    term = c("BackPain", "Physio", "GP", "Chemist", "Depression", "GP", "Chemist", "Psych", "Flu", "GP", "Chemist", "Anxiety", "GP", "Psych", "Toothache", "Dentist"),
    type = c("Condition", "Treater", "Treater", "Treater", "Condition", "Treater", "Treater", "Treater", "Condition", "Treater", "Treater", "Condition", "Treater", "Treater", "Condition", "Treater")
  )
```

I suspect I need a clever pivot_wider type solution OR bypass the above structure altogether to go direct from my source data to the igraph Bipartite format. I searched everywhere and I cannot find similar questions/answers where the data is in a long format.

Any ideas to: 1) convert the long format to the wide format or 2) how to go from the long format directly to an igraph bipartite graph?

Help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert your data into a wide format, you can use:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  filter(type == "Treater") %>% 
  mutate(type = 1 * (type == "Treater")) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = "term", values_from = "type", values_fill = 0) %>% 
  left_join(df %>% filter(type == "Condition"), by = "id") %>% 
  select(Condition = term, Physio, GP, Chemist, Psych, Dentist)
```

which returns

```r
# A tibble: 5 x 6
  Condition  Physio    GP Chemist Psych Dentist
  <chr>       <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>
1 BackPain        1     1       1     0       0
2 Depression      0     1       1     1       0
3 Flu             0     1       1     0       0
4 Anxiety         0     1       0     1       0
5 Toothache       0     0       0     0       1
```

Answer (score 4):

```
library(igraph)
library(magrittr)
library(data.table)
data.table::setDT(df)
DT <- df[!type == "Condition", ][df[type == "Condition", ], on = .(id)]
DT.wide <- dcast(DT, term ~ i.term, value.var = "id", fun.aggregate = length)
graph_from_incidence_matrix(as.matrix(DT.wide, rownames = 1)) %>%
  add_layout_(as_bipartite()) %>%
  plot()
```

[image]

Comment: Great, this works a treat as well. Unfortunately I cannot accept both as answers.

Answer (score 2):

A `data.table` option

```
table(setDT(df)[, expand.grid(split(term, type)), id][, id := NULL])
```

gives

```
            Treater
Condition    Physio GP Chemist Psych Dentist
  BackPain        1  1       1     0       0
  Depression      0  1       1     1       0
  Flu             0  1       1     0       0
  Anxiety         0  1       0     1       0
  Toothache       0  0       0     0       1
```

---

If you want to have the plot, you can add two more lines like below

```
table(setDT(df)[, expand.grid(split(term, type)), id][, id := NULL]) %>%
    graph_from_incidence_matrix() %>%
    plot(layout = layout_as_bipartite)
```

which gives

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another option going from long edge data.frame directly to bipartite graph without incidence matrix:

```
library(igraph)
#create long edges data.frame
d <- do.call(rbind, tapply(df$term, df$id, 
    function(x) data.frame(Condition=x[1L], Treater=x[-1L])))

#create graph
g <- graph_from_data_frame(d, directed=FALSE)

#see https://rpubs.com/pjmurphy/317838 by Phil Murphy & Brendan Knapp
V(g)$type <- bipartite_mapping(g)$type
plot(g, layout=layout_as_bipartite)
```

Comment: It is not a bipartite graph.

Comment: addressed the comment